# Google Cloud SQL: Column Does Not Exist Error When Inserting Row

Tags: sql, google-cloud-sql

I have a SQL table on Google Cloud (which I will call table_name here). It has three columns, which I will refer to as:

1. col_1 (with data type 'character varying')
2. col_2 (with data type 'character varying')
3. col_3 (with data type 'timestamp without time zone')

I am trying to enter a new row with the following query:

```
insert into table_name (col_1, col_2, col_3) 
values ("some_string", "some_string_2", "2021-08-01 04:28:00");
```

However, it is returning an error

> column "some_string" does not exist

All of the data types should be correct, and I'm pretty sure the syntax of this query is correct, so what could be happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change double-quotes to single-quotes:

```
values ('some_string', 'some_string_2', '2021-08-01 04:28:00');
```

Double-quotes are not used to indicate strings in SQL. Enforcement varies with database vendors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using the query

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('some_string', 'some_string_2', TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-08-01 04:28:11', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');
```

I will accept John Hanley's answer, though, as the double quotes were also an error.